# Multiple turbine clusters by specific services

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, turbine

I have two services(spring cloud applications) implementing fallbacks, let's say service1 and service2.
Now i want to have 2 clusters, cluster 1 contains service1 and service 2 and another cluster which only contains dash for service1.

Here is the configuration that doesn't work:

```
turbine:  
  aggregator:
    clusterConfig: CLUSTER1,CLUSTER2
  appConfig: service1,service2
  ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery:
    cluster1: service1,service2
    cluster2: service1
  clusterNameExpression: metadata.cluster
```

Until now i could have a default dashboard with all the services with the following configuration, but i need to have multiple clusters.

```
turbine:
  appConfig: service1,service2
  clusterNameExpression: "'default'"
```

Comment: AFAIK, turbine doesn't support viewing more than one cluster at a time.

Comment: what do you mean by at a time? I think we have this endpoint http://turbinserver:port?cluster=CLUSTERNAME, so i guess many clusters can be configured. Thank you !

Comment: configured, yes, viewable at the same time, no